# Replace value of text box if value matches with master then to yes else to no

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code add a css class if the value of inputs are same but i have a condition where i want to Compare a specific class  "User" text box with master if both's value matches then then make that text box value as yes if Dis matches then make that text box value to no.

HTML:

```
<input class="master" value="1">  
<input class="user" value="1">     
<input class="user" value="1">    
<input class="user" value="0">
<input class="user" value="0">
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.filter(function(i,el){
    return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
        return this.value === el.value;
    }).length !== 0;
}).addClass('red');
```

Comment: where is the master's input?

Comment: @Pekka Sorry it was not commented as code updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```js
$(function() {
  var master = $('input.master').get(0).value; // get the master value
  var fn = function() {
    return this.value === master ? "yes" : "no";//if current text-box matches master,then yes else no
  };
  $('input.user').val(fn); // loop and replace text for each user input
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="master" value="1">
<input class="user" value="1">
<input class="user" value="1">
<input class="user" value="0">
<input class="user" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = $('input.user');

$.each(inputs, function () {
    var user = $(this).val();
    var master = $('.master').val();
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($('.master').val());
    if (user == master) {
        $(this).val('NO');

    }
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e8gsmvec/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.user").change(function(){
    if($("input.master").val() == $(this).val()){
      $(this).val('Yes');
    }
    else{
      $(this).val('No');
    }
});
```

Or even this

```
   $("input.user").change(function(){
        $("input.master").val() == $(this).val()) ? $(this).val('Yes') : $(this).val('No');          
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first wrap the inputs in a parent element, so you know you are comparing to the right master like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- inputs here //-->
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var wrappers = $('.wrapper');
$(wrappers).each(function(i,oWrapper){
    var master_value = $(oWrapper).find('input.master:eq(0)').val();
    var user_inputs = $(oWrapper).find('input.user');
    $(user_inputs).each(function(i,oInput){
        if($(oInput).val() === master_value){
            $(oInput).addClass('red')
                     .val('yes');
        }else{
            $(oInput).removeClass('red')
                     .val('no');
        }
    });
});
```

that should do what you want